# Sharepoint 2013 Suddenly Going Slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I currently have a test SharePoint 2013 install setup on a VM, the specs of the VM are very modest (8GB RAM, Dual Core Xeon, linked to SQL 2012 on another server) and it has been working fine as far as developing the site. The site was pretty quick and responsive for some time but all of a sudden it has become very slow when navigating the site and I can't understand why!?

When I clicked on links before it used to load up pretty much straight away (bar the odd slow down), but now no matter what part of the site I navigate too I get the little "We're working on it" box and have to wait 5-8 seconds for the page to load.

I can't really understand whats made this happen though.  I know SharePoint needs more than 8GB in a production environment but it's confusing me as this was working fine and I was pleased with the performance.

Ive had a look online and done the typical SharePoint 2013 speed fixes (changing the crawl, noderunner memory usage etc) but it doesnt really appear to have done anything.  The site isn't a massive site, its just some calendars, staff directory and a message board so nothing too taxing and there is only me accessing it at the moment.

Don't know if its worth noting it is slow on both a client machine accessing it, and also directly on the server accessing it.  It is also slow in the Central Admin.

I don't know whats happened?!?!  Anyone any ideas?  I can't throw any more RAM at the VM as our ESX host is at capacity now.  We can potentially purchase extra RAM but I'd only be willing to buy it if it was definitely down to a memory issue and that was the resolution but I'm struggling to buy into it being a lack of RAM as the VM hasn't really peaked at anything more than 5GB when I've been using it, its currently idling at 2.59GB.

Anyway sorry for long babble, hopefully I've made sense and someone can offer some help! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Well what do you know, been trying to fix this for a bit and stumbled across this article....

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/15/sharepoint-2013-page-loads-takes-a-very-long-time/

Works a treat now!